# iBeacon on Mountain Lion with Xcode 5.02

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode5, osx-mavericks, ibeacon

Does iBeacon peripheral work with XCode 5.02 or should we need to update to mavericks?
Current OS version is 10.8.4 and it does support Bluetooth 4.0